# Перевод описания знака "Спортивное поведение"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, знаки

В оригинале описание выглядит таким образом:

> Up vote 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a
>   positive score

Сейчас перевод выглядит так:

> 100 ответов получают голос «за» в вопросах, где ваш ответ имеет
>   положительный рейтинг

Перевод по-моему не точно передает смысл знака. Другие ответы не просто получают голоса "За" от всех участников, а именно я отдаю эти голоса.

---

[Transifex:6671](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/48712665?key=d527cbabdeb63b476a7ed7a70f87ef2f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, так.

> 100 раз проголосовать «за» другие ответы на вопросы, где ваш ответ имеет положительный рейтинг.

Comment: Не уверен, что "другие" тут существенно, поскольку за собственный ответ голосовать всё равно нельзя.

Comment: Хм.. что-то мне кавычки не нравятся, но без них будет не то... И ещё множественное число у вопросов вроде не в тему?

Comment: @Qwertiy если там три чужих ответа, можно за каждый получить +1 к счетчику знака.

Comment: "другие ответы на вопросы" - мне "вопросы" не нравится, а не "ответы".

Comment: @NickVolynkin, так исправление планируется или просто проголосовали и разошлись?)

Comment: @PavelParshin: поскольку альтернатив не предложили, только что применил этот вариант. Появится на сайте с ближайшим обновлением боевой базы строк.

Comment: @Qwertiy: предлагайте вариант без «вопросы», я что-то не придумал такого.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я имел в виду, что "вопрос" вместо "вопросы" мне кажется лучше. Но вообще, хотел придумать другую фразу - что-то ничего хорошего не получилось.

Comment: @Qwertiy прошёл год, я перечитал и понял комментарий. Единственное число сделать? «100 раз проголосовать «за» другие ответы на **вопрос**, где...» — так?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не знаю.. Мне что-то оба варианта не очень нравятся. Надо бы что-то новенькое придумать :)