# Поменять описание знака "Спортивное поведение"

Tags: предложение, локализация, знаки

Описание знака "Спортивное поведение", [выбранное](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2195/176217) чуть более года назад, гласит:

> 100 раз проголосовать «за» другие ответы на вопросы, где ваш ответ имеет положительный рейтинг.

Суть знака понятна, однако построение предложения мне ([и не только](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2195/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#comment6460_2196)) кажется ошибочным. В частности, из-за кавычек вокруг "за", которые призваны однозначно сказать, что голосование именно "+1", хотя по правилам русского языка их в этом предложении быть не должно.

Для полноты картины приведу оригинальный текст:

> Up vote 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score

[Transifex:6671](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/48712665?key=d527cbabdeb63b476a7ed7a70f87ef2f)

Answer (score 2):

Ничего менять не надо. И так всё хорошо.

Выбирая этот вариант, вы сознательно идёте на нарушение правил русского языка.

Answer (score 2):

И так всё достаточно хорошо. Разве что я бы вернул "в вопросах", было ведь так когда-то -- а сейчас "на вопросы".

> 100 раз проголосовать «за» другие ответы в вопросах, где ваш ответ имеет положительный рейтинг.

Знаю, что вкусовщина, но в этом  месте лучше бы смотрелось. Но может быть кому-то ещё понравится? ;-)

Comment: Ответы же даются на вопросы, а не в вопросах.

Comment: Та же самая ошибка. Кавычек быть не должно.

Comment: @alexolut Я понимаю, какими правилами вы руководствовались, говоря, что "за" тут должно быть без кавычек. Однако я не очень в этом уверен и вопрос достаточно тонкий, чтобы спросить у бОльших специалистов по русскому языку. Видите ли, есть две кнопки (upvote и downvote) -- в русском языке это кнопка "за" и кнопка "против". Вот вам и появились кавычки, верно? А ещё [открываю первый попавшийся текст про депутатов](https://www.gazeta.ru/politics/2016/06/24_a_8324543.shtml) и вижу что -- оба варианта используются. Так что это спорно. Предлагаю запросить консультацию.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с кавычками, не нарушающий правил русского языка:

> Отдать голос «за» 100 ответам других участников, где ваш ответ имеет положительный рейтинг

Comment: Здесь чего-то не хватает... куда делось "в вопросах" перед "где"? Без него не читается.

Comment: @AK ответы не могут существовать без вопросов. "в вопросах" было [забраковано](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4548/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%a1%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/4555?noredirect=1#comment15859_4551). Попробую ещё один вариант предложить.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлено явно "на вопросы", хотя, имхо, это и так очевидно, т.к. ответы без вопросов существовать не могут:

> Отдать голос «за» 100 ответам других участников на вопросы, где ваш ответ имеет положительный рейтинг

Comment: "где" -> "в которых" не лучше будет?

Comment: @Qwertiy предложите свой вариант :)

Comment: Я уже другой предложил)

Answer (score 0):

> 100 раз поставить плюс конкурирующим ответам в вопросах с вашим ответом, имеющим положительный рейтинг

Ещё бы от повтора слова "ответ" избавиться...

Comment: Я вот подумал: а голосование за другой, но "общий" ответ будет учитываться интересно?

Comment: @alexolut, я тут формулировку немного поменял... Ну или много... сочетание "проголосовать за" само по себе означает как "за", так и "против" в большинстве мест, поэтому в оригинале там кавычки и стоят. Надо его на что-то менять. Минусы наверняка в знак не идут.

Comment: Понятно, что минусы не идут, но искусственное добавление кавычек недопустимо. Мне кажется `проголосовать за` (без кавычек) - это исключительно `+`. А вот `отдать голос` может быть расценено действительно двояко, поэтому имеет смысл добавлять `"за"` или `"против"`.

Comment: @alexolut, неа, проголосовать за - это не только ЗА :) Кстати, а ведь вместо кавычек можно заглавными буквами написать - лучше станет?

Comment: Пример для опровержения приведёте?

Answer (score -1):

Вот ещё вариант. Сделал акцент на конкуренции, объясняющий суть «спортивного поведения». И вторая половина строки хоть и удлинилась, но вроде бы стала звучать лучше, согласованнее.

> 100 раз проголосовать «за» конкурирующие ответы на вопросы, на которые вы сами дали ответ, получивший положительный рейтинг.

Comment: Вокруг "за" кавычек быть не должно при таком варианте. Повторяется та же ошибка, что и сейчас.

Answer (score -1):

Просто убрать кавычки-ёлочки с текущей фразы, т.к. **"проголосовать за"** не может быть интерпретировано как-то иначе, кроме как **+1**:

> 100 раз проголосовать за другие ответы на вопросы, где ваш ответ имеет положительный рейтинг.

Comment: Может. Чисто интуитивно воспринимается как любой голос, не важно, за или против.

Comment: @Qwertiy значит, интуицию ввели в заблуждение. Нельзя говорить **проголосовал за** и при этом подразумевать **несогласие**.

Comment: Кажется, нам с этим вопросом надо на соседний сайт сети :)

Comment: @Qwertiy за ответом на "бета" сайт? :)

Comment: А почему бы нет? Я [Русский язык](//rus.stackexchange.com/) имел в виду)

Comment: @Qwertiy ну, я то уверен в ответе :)

Answer (score -2):

Т.к. при голосовании "за" подсказка на кнопке гласит "Ответ полезен", то можно использовать следующую формулировку:

> Отметить 100 ответов (других участников) полезными в темах, где ваш ответ имеет положительный рейтинг.

Выражение в скобкам можно опустить, т.к. [за свои ответы голосовать нельзя](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2195/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#comment6459_2196).

Comment: Термин «тема» не определён в неймспейсе StackOverflow. :) Да, с точки зрения форума он имеет смысл. Но мы же стараемся подчеркнуть, что здесь не форум.

Comment: Зато хорошо, что явным образом обозначено, что нужно не свои ответы плюсовать. Конечно, это не получится сделать, но всё равно была некоторая неточность.

Comment: А ещё «отметить полезными» может быть перепутано с галочкой.

Comment: @NickVolynkin с "темой" были сомнения, но вдруг :) Отметить галочкой - это принять. А как вообще называется страница, содержащая вопрос?